# What are the reservations of Dynamic Linear Models (DLMs)?

Tags: multiple-regression, overfitting, dynamic-regression

I am studying dynamic linear models (DLMs). I am not sure I understand all its intricacies. My novice take is that those models can work very well if:

1. you have a lot of data (several hundreds of observations);
2. you don't deal with many independent variables;
3. you are mainly concerned about short-term forecasting (just a couple of periods out);
4. variables' statistical significance is not a primary concern.

If the above is correct, it would entail that opposite conditions are situations that would not work well for DLMs: small sample, many independent variables, focused on long-term forecasting, interested in variables' statistical significance. Additionally, an overall concern may be model overfitting. DLM appears to do that most naturally. That's one main reason why it may be ill suited for long-term forecasting.

Comment: The question is quite general, and you have already answered it both in the original post and in the separate answer you posted later. I think it would be easier to analyze a concrete case if you have one. Otherwise what you said perhaps summarizes it all.

Comment: To be honest I am new to DLMs.  I have actually never run such a model.  In certain circles DLMs appear to be the answer to everything just like VAR was a few years ago.  Regarding DLMs, I just wanted to explore under the hood to make sure that if I did use DLMs I would use them in a judicious manner and understand when others have used it in appropriate ways or not.  I most welcome any other answers to expand my knowledge of DLMs.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any answers so far, I have researched this question a bit.  And, what I understand at this stage is that DLMs do have certain vulnerabilities.  The first that comes to mind is overfitting.  By capturing every abrupt up and down turn of the time series, they can generate regression coefficients that are not representative in a Hold Out sample or in forecasting.  Another issue is that DLMs can be unstable.  Depending on how DLMs underlying parameters are specified (somewhat of an arbitrary or judgment process), you can get very different results.  Thus, DLMs are unstable.  DLMs seem unsuited for medium- or long-term forecasting in part because of the mentioned vulnerabilities.  They also seem questionable as a testing tool for regression coefficient stability.  Robust Regressions are a superior tool earmarked for doing so.